# Cannot connect to SQL Compact database 'Access to database file is not allowed' in SSMS

Tags: sql-server-ce, ssms

I'm trying to open an SQL Compact database in SQL Management studio.
If the file is located in my user path then I can open it fine, if it is in a root folder off my C: or D: drive then I get the following error:

Cannot connect to 
'Access to database file is not allowed' (SQL Server Compact ADO.NET data provider)

I have a feeling this could be because I don't have certain permissions but not sure how to resolved. Can anyone guide me into fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why I had this error was because of not having correct local administrator privileges on my Windows account.